# Constructors assign the same value to two unrelated variables

Tags: c++, constructor

As the title says, I got a problem with the same value assigned by two different constructors to two unrelated variables in my program.

This is the first part:

```cpp
template<typename N>
    N* readMany( const json::Value& jsonSource, std::size_t size ) {
        N* result = new N[size];
        
        //check code
        std::cout << "result: " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::flush;
        
        for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            auto number = jsonSource.get( i, false );
            result[i] = static_cast<N>( number.asFloat() );
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

And this is the second part:

```cpp
Value::Value() {
        element = new JsonNull();
        //check code
        std::cout << "Constructor call: " << element << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::flush; 
    }
```

And this is what is printed to stdout:

```
Constructor call: 0x55dd64bfddb0
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23040
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23060
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23080
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23040
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23060
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23080
result: 0x55dd64c23060 <-- HERE
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23080
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23060 <-- AND HERE
Constructor call: 0x55dd64c23040
```

As you can see in two parts of my code the variables got the same values. And because these values are deleted in two other parts of my code in destructors, I'm getting SEGFAULT for double freeing of my memory.

I's using a debugger and then the above print code and got the same results. I don't know what may be the issue. I can't even post any sample code for You to test, because I can't isolate the problem in a sample. The above findings are all what I got.

**EDIT**:

These are destructors:

```cpp
Value::~Value() {
        delete element;
    }
```

```cpp
NumberArray::~NumberArray() {
    delete[] array;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any destructors code. Please post a [mre]. In any case, you can avoid bugs by using `std::vector` instead of raw C arrays, smart pointers instead of raw ones, and avoiding manual `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Which implementation of JSON are you using?

Comment: Possibly you violated the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)? It's *highly* unlikely that your compiler would have borked `new` implementation such that it would return same pointer without `delete` in between. But wohlstad suggestion is the best - don't use raw `new` and `delete` in C++. It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: OK, I got rid of the problem. I still don't know what caused it, but a change to `std::vector` solved it.

Comment: the issue seems to be in code you did not show. Please always try to create a [mcve]